# Apacke Kafka Listener Threads

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Let's say I have **50** Kafka Topics, each with **3** partitions, that's a total of **150** partitions. If I have a KafkaListener/Consumer configured for each of these 150 partitions (due to high volume on each partition), it means I have 150 listeners running. From what I understand, each listener gets its own thread. So does that mean there will be 150 active threads in this scenario? That seems like a lot. Is there any way I could restrict this to a max number of threads at a time(say, 20)?

Answer (score 0):

> Kafka always gives a single partition’s data to one consumer thread

For restricting the thread count to `20` with `150` partitions, you could set the concurrency to `8` which should effectively create 8 separate consumer instances & limit the thread count to a maximum of `<19` (150/8).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60014009/how-to-decide-the-concurrency-to-be-set-in-spring-kafka) is another stack post on the topic which explains it a bit more for setting concurrency in your kafka listener factory. Also [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster/) is another decent source for explaining some of the concepts around kafka topics & partitions.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to **maximize consumption**, yes, you need 150 `consumer threads` on 150 `partitions` (1 consumer thread per partition). In case you only have 20, you can't want to **maximize consumption**, instead, now 1 consumer is responsible for consuming for example 150/20=7 `partitions`. It's a tradeoff.
2. You won't want your app consumes 50 `topics` at a time. It leads to the scale problem. Let say now one topic needs to increase the number of its `partitions` from 3 to 6, you horizontally scale your app from 1 to 2 instances, which means from 150 `consumers` to 300 `consumers` and there are only 150 + (6-3) = 153 active `consumers`, the others become idle.